# Kolmogorov–Smirnov test p-value

Tags: python

I carried out a 2 sample [Kolmogorov–Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) or "KS" test. I got a p-value of 0.11. That means the probability of 2 samples being of the same population is 0.11. Is it correct to say that the probability of the same is 11%?

Comment: May be more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: The p-value usually represents the probability that you would get your results if the null hypothesis (in this case, that the samples are drawn from the same underlying distribution) were true,. You reject the hypothesis if the p-value is less than your predefined notion of a significant difference.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no particular relevance to astronomy that has been made.